# Syntax error when choosing multiple UINT formats on MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have the book Programming Windows with MFC, Second Edition, by Jeff Prosise, but in the very first example this error happens:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '│'
```

In this line:

```
dc.DrawText(_T("Hello, MFC"), -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE │ DT_CENTER │ DT_VCENTER);
```

If I choose only one of those three formats, no error occurs, although, the program doesn't show the text as the book says it would, could anybody help? I've compiled other two examples in the book and they are compiling quite fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've apparently typed the code incorrectly. That's supposed to be a vertical bar (which C and C++ use to mean "bitwise OR"). On US keyboards, that's typically immediately above the <kbd>enter</kbd> key (I suspect you may have entered one of the line drawing characters in the IBM extended character set instead, but it's hard to be sure).

Comment: Thanks, I changed my keyboard to use an English ABNT and typed the vertical bar again, it worked fine :)